# Display the contents of the lotion through Ajax to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

There is a script that gets through JSON data from the PHP-script. The data are fine. I can not get the data to be updated at intervals. Is updated, but the data are duplicated. Here is a working script that simply displays the data without refreshing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
  });
  /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */

  $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' ' + 
      val.event + ' ' + val.region + ' ' + val.host + ' '+ val.type + 
      ' ' + val.info + '</li>');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I came expecting fancy lotions. Now I'm disappointed.

Comment: what do you mean by `I can not get the data to be updated at intervals.` ?

Comment: I need to get to the result page is updated automatically. To automatically request new data occurred in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` to poll your api.php page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup ({  
           cache: false  
        });

        setTimeout(getData, 5000);

      });

      function getData(){
          $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
             /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
             $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' ' + val.event + ' ' + val.region + ' ' + val.host + ' '+ val.type + ' ' + val.info + '</li>');
             });
             setTimeout(getData, 5000);
          });
      }

</script>
```

Comment: Working. But how to get all the data in the cycle? So it takes only 1 row.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin I'm sorry I don't understand your question can you please explain further.

Comment: Now the result of only 1 line.
2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075

Comment: Must be all the rows from JSON

[{ "Date": "2016-09-09 09:12:18", "event": "WARN", "region": "SZ", "host": "SIU05", "type": "[main ] "," info ":" Started, locked port 7075 "}, {" date ":" 2016-09-09 09:37:03 "," event ":" WARN "," region ":" SZ ", "host": "SIU05", "type": "[main]", "info": "Started, locked port 7075"}, { "date": "2016-09-09 09:12:18", " event ":" WARN "," region ":" MRP "," host ":" SIU05 "," type ":" [main] "," info ":" Started, locked port 7075 "}

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work unless your JSON is malformed, something you will need to figure out on your end.